# Need standard name for short depth drawers

Tags: bathroom, drawers

I'm looking for a set of drawers for use in my bathroom for storage.

I'm looking for a set or modular range that has a small depth length in dimension. In other words the distance between the front and rear of the drawer is small, of maximum length 18cm.

The reason is that I want to put the drawers on a step-like tiled surface on one side of the room that is of depth of about 18cm.

I'm having difficulty telling the search engine that I don't want "deep" depth drawers. Some online shops do provide a filter for depth length, but not all. So I wondered if there was a standard naming convention for small length depths that I could use with general search engines.

Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that it's trivial to shorten wooden drawers if you have a table saw available, or with a miter saw and circular saw, or even with nothing but a hand saw.

Comment: +1  upvote thank you @isherwood for your input but I would like to work with a cleaner / smoother finish material than wood. I'm thinking of plywood with a thin vinyl-like or melamine smoother teflon-like finish.  I did try "hacking" some Ikea Moppe drawers which were already the right depth. My hack was to create further drawer sizes including spanning multiple levels. But the quality of my own work with this disappointing (rough edges, excess glue).  1 / 2

Comment: 2 / 2 Now, I'm either thinking of buying a product or maybe made-to-measure custom plywood with white vinyl-like/melamine sides which I would assemble and add my own ball bearing rails bought at a specified short length for a smooth gliding motion.  I found the wood solution a bit rickety and shunty in movement.